# SO tags not appending to URL when clicking on it

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags

I was checking the **Unanswered section** in SO. Then I clicked **java** tag to get Java related questions. The url was

**https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/java**

Then I clicked on **javascript** tag. The URL became

**[https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/java)**

This happened today only. Yesterday and all when I click another tag, the URL would append the tag. ie,

[**https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/java+javascript**](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/java+javascript)

Why its happening? Earlier was easy. Now for more tags, we need to type URL, instead of clicking each tag?

Comment: The behavior is different if you don't pick the "Unanswered" top-level "tab" (i.e. the big orange button), but rather stay on the "Questions" section, then the "Unanswerd" "sub-tab". You get the behavior you describe with this second method. (But this might be a bug. Or not.)

Comment: May be they have removed the feature

Comment: How to get back to old one?

Comment: looking into that...

Comment: Just click on the "Questions" orange button at the top, then select a tag, then select the "Unanswered" sub-tab. You'll get for ex. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?sort=unanswered&pagesize=15

Comment: I don't know, whether I should ask here. What is the difference between **unanswered** as sub of **Questions** and the **Unanswered** on top?

Comment: the _unanswered sub of questions_ starts off blank (no tag filtering), while the _unanswered on top_ starts by already filtering by your favorite tags (in the my tags - sub page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for pointing it out. Fixed in build 2013.8.21.1365 (meta) and 2013.8.21.959 (sites).

Comment: It didn't work for me.

Comment: check the build numbers on the bottom of the page

Comment: its `rev 2013.8.20.958` in stackoverflow.com

Comment: When I'll get the updated?

Comment: Yeah. Now I got. Thanks